# Highlight Woocommerce admin orders list when order contains a regular product

Tags: woocommerce, styles

I am using Woocommerce and YITH Subscription plugin to sell a subscription product. But when people also order a regular product I often overlook that (~95% of the orders are subscriptions).

Is there a way I can highlight/style the respective line in the admin orders list when an order also contains a regular product so it doesn't get overlooked?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `post_class` filter hooks to add class to a table row.

First, you have to check `get_current_screen()` to make sure that you are adding a class to the order list page.

Now you have to get order items and need to check the product is a subscription or not using product meta `_ywsbs_subscription`

```
function add_custom_class( $classes, $class, $post_id ){
    // Check current screen and make sure you are only doing in order list page.
    $currentScreen = get_current_screen();
    if( $currentScreen->id === "edit-shop_order" ) {
        // Getting an instance of the WC_Order object from a defined ORDER ID
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id ); 

        $has_regular = false;

        // Iterating through each "line" items in the order      
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            if( $product && $product->is_type('simple') ){
                if( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_ywsbs_subscription', true ) == 'no' || get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_ywsbs_subscription', true ) == '' ){
                    $has_regular = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if( $has_regular ){
            $classes[] = 'order-has-simple';
        }

    }
    return $classes;
}   
add_filter( 'post_class', 'add_custom_class', 10, 3 );
```

Now you have to use `admin_head` hooks that help you to add CSS on the admin side.

```
function add_custom_admin_css(){
    $currentScreen = get_current_screen();
    if( $currentScreen->id === "edit-shop_order" ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .order-has-simple{
                background-color: #adf !important; // here you have to your own color
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_admin_css', 10, 1 );
```

Tested and works.

[image]

**As per OP requested**

[image]

**Check products by category**

```
function add_custom_class( $classes, $class, $post_id ){
    // Check current screen and make sure you are only doing in order list page.
    $currentScreen = get_current_screen();
    if( $currentScreen->id === "edit-shop_order" ) {
        // Getting an instance of the WC_Order object from a defined ORDER ID
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id ); 

        $has_regular = false;

        // Iterating through each "line" items in the order      
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            if( $product && has_term( 'vergangene-ausgaben', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
                $has_regular = true;
                break;
            }               
        }
        if( $has_regular ){
            $classes[] = 'order-has-simple';
        }

    }
    return $classes;
}   
add_filter( 'post_class', 'add_custom_class', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Wow, that was really helpful. Thank you for that!

The thing is that there are also orders with a subscription and a regular product as well. It's mostly these I'd like to highlight. How can I make these being highlighted as well?

This does not work with $has_subscription = false;

Comment: Still doesn't work with orders that contain both - subscription and regular product. And highlighting the regular only orders doesn't work anymore.

Comment: can you give screenshots of orders that contain only subscription and simple and subscription? and which do you want to highlight as well?

Comment: Screenshot: https://ibb.co/cFqfPR9

#5313 is an order with a subscription AND a regular product but it is impossible to identify it in the orders list since it has a subscription ID (#5314)

Orders with a regular product only do not have a subscription number and are easier to identify but I'd like to have them highlighted as well.

Comment: Do you only want to highlight that has both a subscription AND a regular product or also want to highlight regular products as well?

Comment: Highlighting either a regular product only or in combination with a subscription. No highlighting for subscriptions only.

Comment: The above my updated answer is working fine for me. I have tested in my local.

Comment: no highlighting at all. neither combined orders nor regular only orders.

Comment: Not sure why is not working for you. I think you have to more debug on that part.

Comment: Is it possible and helpful to differenciate between the categories? My regular product has its own category ('vergangene-ausgaben') and the subscription has its respective category ('aktiv-abo')

Comment: Yes, it is possible I will back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238698/discussion-between-bhautik-and-hans-dampf).