# Highlight WooCommerce admin orders list based on order shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to highlight the admin order list line based on the order shipping method. (specifically for local pickup)

Based on [Highlight WooCommerce admin orders list based on order payment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061142/highlight-woocommerce-admin-orders-list-based-on-order-payment-method/75224928)
anwser code, I have changed $payment_method for $shipping_method and .type-shop_order.cod for .type-shop_order.local_pickupcode for shipping methods but it did nothing in admin panel
I have also tried using shipping method title instead of $shipping_method, but it did nothing.

i have also tried to get all classes with

```
public function get_shipping_classes() {
        if ( empty( $this->shipping_classes ) ) {
            $classes                = get_terms(
                'product_shipping_class',
                array(
                    'hide_empty' => '0',
                    'orderby'    => 'name',
                )
            );
            $this->shipping_classes = ! is_wp_error( $classes ) ? $classes : array();
        }
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_shipping_classes', $this->shipping_classes );
    }
```

but it hid all orders except local pickup.

Here is the code:

```
function filter_post_class( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {
    // Determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page
    if ( ! is_admin() ) return $classes;

    // Get the current screen object
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    // Only when
    if ( $current_screen->id === 'edit-shop_order' ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

        // Is a WC_Order
        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            // Get the payment method
            $shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method();
            
             //NOT empty
            if ( ! empty( $shipping_method ) ) {
                $classes[] = $shipping_method;
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Return the array
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'filter_post_class', 10, 3 );

// Add CSS
function action_admin_head() {
    // Get the current screen object
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    // Only when
    if ( $current_screen->id === 'edit-shop_order' ) {
        echo '<style>
            .type-shop_order.local_pickup {
                background-color: #e9a5a5 !important;
            }
            
        </style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'action_admin_head' );
```

Any advice how to change it please? i am not php coder so this is kinda google try thing for me :/

Comment: "Doesn't work" as a problem description is not very useful. What have you done so far, to try and figure out where the problem lies? Have you checked what you got in `$shipping_method`? What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Not what I asked you.

Comment: I meant, go check what the resulting HTML code looks like. "View source code" in your browser or something. _"i have updated my question"_ - and yet still not answered my question. Go and check what the variable `$shipping_method` actually contains, after `$shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method();`

Comment: i have used echo $shipping_method; but i can not see anything in source code.

Comment: echo isn't a very good tool for debugging - if the variable contained an empty string or NULL, you'd get no visible output at all. `var_dump` also shows you type and length of a value.

Comment: echo '<pre>' , var_dump($shipping_method) , '</pre>'; returned every order on the screen with this formar:

iedit author-self level-0 post-18165 type-shop_order status-wc-processing post-password-required hentry DPD kuriér na adresu">

Comment: That makes little sense. Why should the _shipping method_ contain information such as `author-self level-0 post-18165`? That very much looks like the already set _classes_ that get passed into the filter to begin with.

Comment: i have changed $shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method(); to $shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_methods(); to be able to see all data, now i see ["method_id"]=>
        string(12) "local_pickup" but i have no idea what to do with that

Comment: Use the array key `method_id` to access the value ...?

Comment: thank you mate, i am not debugger and this is first time i did something like this :D i wanted to blame you for your answers, but u did get me there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made it thanks to CBroe.

```
function filter_post_class( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {
    // Determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page
    if ( ! is_admin() ) return $classes;

    // Get the current screen object
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    // Only when
    if ( $current_screen->id === 'edit-shop_order' ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

        // Is a WC_Order
        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            // Get the shipping method
            $shipping_method = @array_shift($order->get_shipping_methods());
            $shipping_method_id = $shipping_method['method_id'];
            
             //NOT empty
            if ( ! empty( $shipping_method ) ) {
                $classes[] = $shipping_method_id;
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Return the array
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'filter_post_class', 10, 3 );

// Add CSS
function action_admin_head() {
    // Get the current screen object
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    // Only when
    if ( $current_screen->id === 'edit-shop_order' ) {
        echo '<style>
            .type-shop_order.local_pickup {
                background-color: #e9a5a5 !important;
            }
            
        </style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'action_admin_head' );
```